# React architecture with angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, reactjs

I'm working on a big SPA application (MVC4) that is mostly angular based. I'm making some directives and I want to use react to do some of the rendering (watching directive's data or event triggering, I even made a demo for my coworkers [here](https://github.com/yuvalsaraf/demoClient1)).
JSX is not an option, and I saw some use react factories instead but only with browsify which is also not an option. How should I build the folders architecture of react? divide to factories and classes?

Comment: Why JSX and Browserify are not an option? They can be used anywhere with any project.

Answer (score 0):

Use [ngReact](http://davidchang.github.io/ngReact/)

You can simply create Classes as global variable, or as Angular modules to avoid Browserify. You can also use the `--standalone` flag with browserify to wrap a deep React component, (component of components) to be wrapped into a single component. (Be sure to not include React as a dependency to avoid multiple copies for multiple components)

You can use vanilla JS instead of JSX. Or you can easily use the JSX compiler even with non-CommonJS React code.